# Desktop and access denied issue

Tags: windows-7

I have a custom built PC with Windows 7 Ultimate and it is already nearly 1 year old and it worked just fine. I am a student that follow the studies of electrical engineering. That oftens create electric schematics for school and put it in the "Document" folder of the library.
I dont have many knowledge about computers (the software part). Once a week I scan for virus with Kaspersky internet security and it could't not find any virus. Sometimes I download anime's ( yes I watch anime's) and put it in the video folder library.
My computer worked just fine when i was playing a game and checked the e-mail thats all. No problem.....

Until the next day when I start my computer and my little brother pressed the reset button on my PC chassis because he want to irritate me or wtf.
My PC reset and it does it everyday startup, everything looked fine but then after the message "Welcome" I got a another message that says:
"The Group Policy Client service failed the logon. Access is denied." after this error it logged off and returned to the account selection screen.
I don't know what it means...so I restart my computer again. After the restart I got the same error again. Then I tried to restart my computer on "Safe mode" and it logged in my account without getting the error: "The Group Policy Client service failed the logon. Access is denied.".

But, when it logged in successfully in Safe mode, there where unexpected things that i have never seen and I dont know why. First is that the background of my desktop is black and all my dekstop icons and files are missing. 
Secondly when I got to "Computer" (windows logo+E or windows orb --> computer) my Library files (videos,pictures,documents) are missing on the left panel.
So the first thing I did is right mouse click and clicking on "Show all folder" but nothing happened. So the second thing I did is right click on Library and click on 
"Restore default library" and the videos, picture and documents folder where restored, so I had some relief. But, when I click on the video folder to check if my anime series and really important school documents are save, but they were missing.

Now I have checked my  user profile at "C/users/Eric" and I have:

Appdata
Contacts
desktop
Ntuser

Here is the screenshot of it: h/
[image]

And I have tried what most peoples suggest but to no avail:

Chkdsk :  didnt found any problem.
SFC/scannow: found corrupted files, not all the files are repaired.
system recovery: tried 10 times even at boot but didnt helped my problem.....

I checked the regedit for the register because I followed the steps from a guy that helped someone with nearly the same issue from a answered thread from other forum. Saying that  a register is corrupted and have to look for registers that are the same with one that have .BAK behind its name and removing the one without the .bak and rename the one with .bak to normal:

So i followed it:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE---->SOFTWARE--->MICROSOFT--->WINDOWS NT--->CURRENT VERSION--->PROFILELIST.

and i got those registers:

S-1-5-18
S-1-5-19
S-1-5-20
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1000.bak
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1007
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1008

So there are NO registers which are the same but i tought by renaming "S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1000.bak" to
"S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1000" the problems are solved.

Now my registers are:

S-1-5-18
S-1-5-19
S-1-5-20
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1000
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1007
S-1-5-21-487321731-627411630-2395495840-1008

But it didn't........

someone from another forum told me to create a new account and migrate my user profile to the new account. 
So I created a new account and named my new account "Eric lol 2".(because I cant think of a other name ;p)

With my new account i can log in without safe mode and without the error message: "The Group Policy Client service failed the logon. Access is denied." 
But this account have also some issues....

With this new account the desktop is black and all the icons are missing and get the error message that it 
" Couldnt locate C:windows/system32/config/systemprofile/desktop".
Everytime I go to to "Computer" (windows logo+E or windows orb --> computer) I get the same error message:
" Couldnt locate C:windows/system32/config/systemprofile/desktop". 
And in my users folder by "Computer" there is no "Eric lol 2" user profile folder. Even if i go to folder option in configurationpanel and set the option "Show hidden files".

Now I dont know what to do.... 
I didn't made a backup so i regret it now..... and maybe i shouldn't have to touch the registers?? I dont know......

Some peoples says that I have to delete my user profile. But if I do that will all my files deleted? I am very reluctant with this since i dont have much knowledge about computers and I am afraid that I will never get my files back. (anime's documents, contacts and pictures etc.).

I have those problems for nearly 6 days and it is really time consuming.
So at this point I am panicking because I think I have lost all my anime's, pictures, electrical schematics and important school documents. None of the answered thread from the other forums helped.
Sorry that I have wrote too much. It is my first time to write my problem on a forum. I hope you can understand what i wrote since my english 
is not at a high level ;). Those issues are really frustrating and I dont know why it happened so suddenly.

If you can't understand some parts I will try to explain it better.
Those issues are really frustrating and I dont know why it happened so suddenly.
Thank you for your generous assistance.

Comment: could you try using wubi or some other linux install method to see if the files are actually there? It'll ignore windows permissions and would be a good way to get the files out

Comment: What is a wubi and how can I see with wubi if the files are there? sorry I dont have that much knowledge about computers ;)

Comment: [ubuntu variant you can install/uninstall from windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141031/how-do-i-format-an-ssd-to-be-used-as-the-hibernation-drive-acer-s3) which can access NTFS drives. If the files are there, then you can copy out the files to some USB hard drive or something.

Comment: Ok and then reinstall windows7 after extracting the files?

Comment: or delete the account. Let me know if it worked so i can post it as a proper answer ;)

Comment: Ok I will download and try it later im at work atm xD. I will tell if it worked or not.

Comment: You can also try to repair the windows.......

Comment: I did that when I got the errors, but it couldn't detect the problem....

Comment: Well i have wubu installed and start the computer with the linux, but i have no idea what to do now.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue and followed these [steps](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2eb4224d-3e8b-4705-8ed0-260012be2081/location-not-available-cwindowssystem32configsystemprofiledesktop-is-not-accessible-access?forum=winservergen) and added the following:

1. Login with the new account(the new account must have administrative rights) credentials copy the user files (My documents,my music etc....) to the new user account.
2. Log-off and re-login with the old account and the desktop issue should be fixed.
3. You can now delete the new account you created for backup purposes.